# having trouble parsing XML data with javascript and prototype 1.7

Tags: xml, ajax, prototypejs, javascript

I have a basic question relating to AJAX, XML, and Prototype.

I am trying to parse this XML Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <NavigationData>
    <OrderOfCategories>
      <CategoryName Num="1">location</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="2">real_estate</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="3">services</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="4">learning</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="5">automobile</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="6">personals</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="7">community</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="8">for_sale</CategoryName>
      <CategoryName Num="9">classifides</CategoryName>
    </OrderOfCategories>
  </NavigationData>
```

using this javascript code (for an example):

```
function createNav (response)   {

  var xmlData = response.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CategoryName")[1].childNode[0].nodeValue;

  window.alert(xmlData);

 }
 // end of FUNCTION createNav

 function loadNav ()    {

     new Ajax.Request("http://www.listedcities.com/listings/geo_templates/freshstart/external/xml/global_data.xml",
              {
                method: 'get',
                                contentType: 'text/xml', 
                onSuccess: createNav,
                onFailure: function () { window.alert("failed") }
              });
 }
```

The function loadNav loads the XML file and passes it on to the other function to be parsed.  The reason for this is that the application loads multiple xml files rather than one large file and the filenames for the smaller XML files are stored in the 'global_data.xml' XML file.

The issue I run into with this code is that the alert passes on a 'null' value or in some cases doesn't fire anything at all.

I am hoping to get the alert to fire with the 1st node value in the 'global_data.xml' file.

Any help would be much appreciated around these parts.

Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to hack away at the issue to get this line of code that worked:

```
var xmlData = response.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("CategoryName")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

I needed the extra

```
childNodes[x]
```

reference in there.